# How to Set a Permanent PATH for npm on Unix/Linux Systems

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, export, bin

I've encountered an issue with npm not working properly in my Unix/Linux environment. To temporarily resolve the issue, I executed the following command in my terminal:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH
```

After setting the temporary PATH, running npm start worked fine. However, since this solution is temporary and resets after closing the terminal, I'm looking for a way to permanently set the PATH environment variable to include the necessary directories for npm to operate correctly.

How can I permanently modify the PATH environment variable to ensure npm works without needing to reset the PATH every time I open a new terminal session?